# VBA check if cell contains a year

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA line of code to check if a cell contains a year if this format 199[0-9] OR 20[0-2][0-2].

The code loops from the first row in Column A to the last row in the sheet.

Something like this:

```
finalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = finalRow To 2 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "199[0-9]" OR "20[0-2][0-2]") = 0 Then
        Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
```

I appreciate your cooperation.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the regular expression library to evaluate the year patterns.  The object can store the pattern and later evaluate it against the cell values in your loop.

**Example:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()
    
    ' Setup Regular Expression Object
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    RegEx.Pattern = "199[0-9]|20[0-2][0-2]"  ' Define pattern here
    
    ' Delete rows that match year pattern
    Dim i As Integer, ws As Worksheet, finalRow As Integer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    finalRow = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    
    For i = finalRow To 1 Step -1
        If RegEx.test(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked as intended! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function. It returns all occurrences, if more than one:

```
Private Function containsYear(x As String) As Variant
    Dim regEx As New RegExp, strPattern As String, strInput As String
    Dim matchC As MatchCollection, arr() As Long, El, k As Long
   
        strPattern = "([0-9]{4})" 'search for 4 consecutive numbers

        If strPattern <> "" Then
              strInput = x
            With regEx
                .Global = True: .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False: .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
                Set matchC = regEx.Execute(strInput)
                ReDim arr(matchC.count - 1)
                For Each El In matchC
                    If CLng(El) >= 1990 And CLng(El) <= 2022 Then
                        arr(k) = El: k = k + 1
                    End If
                Next
                ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1)
                containsYear = arr()
            Else
                containsYear = Array("no Match")
            End If
        End If
 End Function
```

It can be checked in this way:

```
Sub testContainsYear()
   Dim x As String, arr() As Long, El
   
    x = "This year, 2021 is better than 2020."
    x = "This year, 2021 is better than 1890." 'comment it to check the above line...
   arr = containsYear(x)

   If UBound(arr) = 0 Then
      If arr(0) <> "no Match" Then
          Debug.Print "Found a year: " & arr(0)
      Else
          Debug.Print "No any year could be found..."
      End If
  Else
        For Each El In arr
            Debug.Print "Found year " & El
        Next
  End If
End Sub
```

If you do not need to return the occurrences, it can return a boolean (`True`). please, use the next function, in such a case:

```
Private Function containsYear(x As String) As Boolean
    Dim regEx As New RegExp, strPattern As String, strInput As String
    Dim matchC As MatchCollection, arr() As Long, El, k As Long
   
        strPattern = "([0-9]{4})" 'search for 4 consecutive numbers

        If strPattern <> "" Then
              strInput = x
            With regEx
                .Global = True: .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False: .Pattern = strPattern
            End With

            If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
                Set matchC = regEx.Execute(strInput)
                ReDim arr(matchC.count - 1)
                For Each El In matchC
                    If CLng(El) >= 1990 And CLng(El) <= 2022 Then
                        containsYear = True: Exit Function
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                containsYear = False
            End If
        End If
 End Function
```

It can be tested as:

```
Sub testContainsYear()
   Dim x As String, arr() As Long, El
   
    x = "This year, 2021 is better than 2020."
    x = "This year, 1542 was better than 1890." 'comment it to check the above line...
   Debug.Print containsYear(x)
End Sub
```

To use the function for processing the existing values in A:A column, should be simple. Declare a range variable `rngDel` where to keep cells when the function returns `True`. Firstly, set the range, then using `Union` and delete all rows at the end (`If Not rngDel Is  Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete'). If not clear enough, I can help with the code, too.